# Reference a cell in another workbook. And make my query not refresh if values are equal

Tags: database, excel, vba

It says I have too few parameters expected 15... It is something with my before and after refresh.

Class 1

```
Public WithEvents qt As QueryTable


Private Sub qt_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("A1") = Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("C1")
   Application.Run "'Operation Get Ipads.xls'!Assembly1_Button"


End Sub
```

Class 2

```
Public WithEvents qut As QueryTable

Private Sub qut_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
    Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("C1") = _
        "='H:\Departments\Manufacturing\Production Links\DashBoard Breakdown\[MASTER_LIVE_STATUS_DATA.xls]Sheet1'!R1C1"
    If Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("C1") = Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("A1") Then
    Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Initialize:

```
Dim T As New Class1
Dim H As New Class2



Sub Initialize_It()
  Set T.qt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).QueryTables(1)
  Set H.qut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).QueryTables(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh and the "MASTER" workbook will not be open while running the refresh.  I need to reference that workbook explicitly.  I do not know if I will have to put the location of the file in there to do that or what it takes.

Comment: "I am not positive this will work." What happens when you try it? (You can't be positive until you try.)

Comment: It does not work.  I do not know if it is my referencing or if I am going about this wrong

Comment: "It does not work" is not helpful. Do you get an error and, if so, what is it?

Comment: "[Mircosoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few Parameters. Expected 15"

Comment: Where is cancel declared in your code. It is not recognized when I paste your code into Excel.  Also, do you know which line causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub qt_BeforeRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
```

the argument is usually `Cancel` and this is what your code refers to. Change it to `Cancel`.

You can refer to the current workbook (where this code is running) as `ThisWorkbook`. Assuming it is the MASTER one, then you can use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
```

The `Workbooks` collection refers only to open workbooks, so you will need to temporarily open the other workbook:

```
Dim wbOther As Workbook

Set wbOther = Workbooks.Open("full path and filename.xlsx", False)
```

the `False` argument indicates that you do not wish to `Update Links` when opening the book (if appropriate).

When you have finished with the other book, use:

```
wb.Close False    'False says that you do not need to Save Changes
Set wb = Nothing
```

---

It is possible to get a single value from another workbook without opening and closing it, but if that book also has links this may cause an issue:

```
Debug.Print ExecuteExcel4Macro("'F:\Documents and Settings\student\My Documents\[AndysData7.xlsx]Staff List'!R6C4")
```

Note, the formula needs to use R1C1 notation. (Rather than `Debug.Print` you would store the value in a variable.) Note also that I am not necessarily recommending this approach, as it is undocumented, but thought I'd mention it in the context of the question.

Comment: Thanks I am doing something like the last one on your post.  That part is working fine now.  I still have too few parameters and do not think I am setting up my before or after refresh subs correctly.  I created two Class Modules to try and make it work.  Still wont.  I will edit my code in my question to show what I have now.

Comment: There is a (short and old) guide [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213187). You are setting qt and qut to the same query-table, which doesn't sound right. A common issue is not putting the code in the correct Module. Hint: Start with a simple MsgBox to prove that the events are firing ok ;)

Comment: With the "Too few parameters" error, cancel your code for the moment and make sure the qt's are still updating okay.

Comment: I was using that same link you gave me.  I tried to copy it and tried only calling the table once the first time I ran this. It gave me the same error.

Comment: It's a little difficult to advise you at this point. I would delete all the code, make sure the query-table(s) are all working, and dig around for a more detailed tutorial.